# For a family of extensions of sheaves, does nonsplit over generic fibre imply nonsplit over special fibre?

Tags: schemes, sheaf-cohomology

Let $A\subseteq K$ be discrete valuation ring in its field of fractions. Let $\kappa:=A/\mathfrak m$ be the residue field. Let $X$ be a scheme, flat and projective over $A$. Consider a short exact sequence of coherent $\mathcal O_X$-modules, which are flat over $A$
$$0\to\mathcal F_1\to \mathcal F\to\mathcal F_2\to0$$

If we have that
$$0\to\mathcal F_1\otimes_AK\to\mathcal F\otimes_AK\to\mathcal F_2\otimes_AK\to0$$
does not split, then can we also have that
$$0\to\mathcal F_1\otimes_A\kappa\to\mathcal F\otimes_A\kappa\to\mathcal F_2\otimes_A\kappa\to0$$
does not split?